# MPI Reduce Program is not working, I`m always getting the error as work ( ) identifier not found

Tags: c++, mpi

```
int myrank,
        numprocs;
    double mytime,   /*variables used for gathering timing statistics*/
        maxtime,
        mintime,
        avgtime;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  /*synchronize all processes*/
    mytime = MPI_Wtime();  /*get time just before work section */
   work();
    mytime = MPI_Wtime() - mytime;  /*get time just after work section*/
    /*compute max, min, and average timing statistics*/
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &maxtime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &mintime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&mytime, &avgtime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (myrank == 0) {
        avgtime /= numprocs;
        printf("Min: %lf  Max: %lf  Avg:  %lf\n", mintime, maxtime, avgtime);
    }
```

In here I'm always getting as

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'work': identifier not found    Activity1   C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Self Study\MPI\Activity1\Activity1.cpp    39
```

this is a code I got from a tutorial, So I do not have a good knowledge of c++. So please help me in this case. I'm tried this many times.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>   ,these are the my imports

Comment: Did the tutorial said you have to implement the `work` subroutine?

Comment: please edit your question with all the necessary bits to compile.

Comment: https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~pollock/367/manual/node23.html  ,this is the link of the tutorial @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: The tutorial suggests you need to implement the `work()` subroutine you want to time.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a code segment from the MPI reduce example code from a tutorial, the work() function needs to be added to the code as follows to take the time of execution. Here we are using a dummy function to stimulate the workload.
As I know work() is not an inbuilt function of c++.

```
void work(){
    for(int i =0; i< INT16_MAX; i++) {
        //simulate the workload
    }
}
```